# Getting information from an Amazon EC2 instance using Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am looking to read the following information from my running Amazon EC2 instances.

1. Instances having S3 access
2. Instances having console account
3. Instances having Elastic IP and having Elastic IP open to the internet.

I have found the [Developer Guide here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-ec2.html) but am unable to get the above details. I am new to AWS SDK. How do I get the above details? Is there any API available for that? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you launched any of these EC2 instances with an IAM role then I presume you are familiar with IAM policies so you can work out which have S3 access, programmatically or otherwise. Can you clarify what you mean by "Instances having console account"? Do you mean EC2 instances that were launched with a key pair (for SSH access)?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few example of using the Java V2 EC2 API to obtain information about an EC2 instance in the Github repo here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/ec2/src/main/java/com/example/ec2

However, the information that you are seeking - such as Instances having S3 access - is not part of the API. For example, there is no method exposed by the EC2 Java API that provides information about Amazon S3 access.

I recommend that you look at the [EC2 Client JavaDocs](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/Ec2Client.html) to learn about the available functionality of this API.